# Static values not getting assigned and returning null value

Tags: java, static, junit

I have something like

```
public class Toys {

public static Toy BAT = Registry.getToy("BAT");
public static Toy DOLL = Registry.getToy("DOLL");

}
```

where Registry keeps tracks of all the objects of type Toy. When provided with a key, it will return with the valid Toy instance.

When I do, Toys.BAT, it gives me null value, but Registry.getToy("BAT") returns me with valid Toy instance.

public class Registry {

```
private static final HashMap<String, Toy>  _toysMap = new HashMap<String, Toy>();


public static void putToy( String toyCode, Toy toy) {
    _toysMap.put( toyCode, Toy ) ;
}

public static Toy getToy(String toyCode ) {
    return _toysMap.get( toyCode);
}
```

}

Is there anything very obvious that I missing ?

Also , I am calling Registry.getToy("BAT") and Toys.getToy("BAT") at the same time ..

Here's the TestRegistry which fails

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestRegistry {

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Toys.BAT);
    Registry.putToy("BAT", new Toy());
    Registry.putToy("DOLL", new Toy());
}

@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println(Registry.getToy("BAT"));
    System.out.println(Toys.BAT);
    assertTrue(Registry.getToy("BAT") == Toys.BAT);
}
```

}

The above prints

null - Registry doesnt contain the toy

Toy@80cac9 - Registry has the toy now

null - Toys.BAT still has null value .

Comment: This piece of string I have here in my hands... how long is it? :P  Without the full source code for your Registry object, we might as well shake a magic 8 ball.

Comment: We would need to see `Registry` and how you are putting things into it.

Comment: When in the program flow are you calling Toys.BAT?

Comment: In all likelihood the code above is being run before the toys have been set in the Registry

Comment: I have attached the Registry code. Its just a hashmap ..

Comment: I had a small typo with the case "Ball" .. I am passing the exact string as the key .

Comment: Did you get so far a satisfying answer? If yes, you should accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Surely looking into the code of `Registry` is necessary to know where the problem is.

But generally, it is not safe to initialize your static variables like that. Maybe at the loadig time of the `Toys` class the `Registry` still did not load all the toys entries correctly.

Comment: Say, during initial loading of Toys class , all values were null. If the Registry gets updated later and adds all toy entries .. and Toy.BALL is called then .. will it still return null value ?

Comment: @sbose The static variables are initialized once when the class is loaded. That is usually the first time the class is used. This first time can be a very tricky for an example in a container.

Answer (score 1):

did you checked the case of Bat and BAT

Comment: wait for more details. right now it is pure speculation. Maybe getToy() has an empty body, we don't know.

Comment: this means `Registry.getToy("Bat")` and `Registry.getToy("BAT")` are different

Answer (score 0):

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Toys.BAT); --> Loads class and initializes static variables
    Registry.putToy("BAT", new Toy()); --> populates Registry (HashMap)
    Registry.putToy("DOLL", new Toy()); --> populates Registry (HashMap)
}
```

You need to initialize the values in the registry **before** your Toys class gets loaded. I agree with the commenters that said its not a good way to initialize these.